# JQuery - hiding a column table

Tags: jquery

as you can see on this jfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/4NgxB/1/ , I have a simple table as here:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="mybutton" value="mybutton" /></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="mybutton" value="mybutton" /></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="mybutton" value="mybutton" /></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tdoby>
</table>
```

where on load it should hide column with this code:

```
$('#mytable tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').hide();
```

so I can show it later in the execution...as I read somewhere this nth-child(n) should apply what I as to that column.. why in this case it didn't applied? Maybe nth-child works only on certain structure of tables?

Comment: I have just created a jsfiddle for you. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `two error` in your code

1) You did not include any jquery file
2) not closed close bracket

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#mytable tbody tr :nth-child(3)').hide();
});
 ^^^^-------close the Bracket
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4NgxB/4/)

Comment: You are not getting rid of the table header.

Answer (score 1):

There's a small syntax error with your code, you forget to close the close parenthesis of the ready handler,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mytable tbody tr :nth-child(3)').hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4NgxB/7/)

Comment: You are not getting rid of the table header.

Comment: Same as my answer. No need to have these kind of comments.

Comment: Thanks for deleting the offensive comment. At least you realized it was not polite to say such a thing. Not sure if it was you or the moderators. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @AlexIncarnati I usually get tensed while seeing a crappy code, anyway bala just grasped the concept that was written by me under the comment section of yours and he made a good answer. By the way, i should not represented you with that word, mistake was mine. Now your answer looks good. DV will be removed from your post soon.  :|

Comment: I appreciate you writing this. It's very nice of you. I will remove immediately the downvote and upvote you. Sometimes it's good to wait for users to see their mistakes and instead of downvoting, it's better to point out in a comment what it's wrong. Thanks Rajabprabhu :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing round bracket and also you were not loading jQuery in your jsFiddle.

nth-child works perfectly well in here.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#mytable tbody tr :nth-child(3)').hide();
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/4NgxB/8/

Comment: When you downvote you need to explain why. :)

Comment: I am a downvoter, why do you use two times this code  $('#mytable tbody tr th:nth-child(3)').hide();
    $('#mytable tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').hide();

Comment: One is for the table header and one if for the table row :) I gave for granted he wanted to get rid of the whole column :)

Comment: @AlexIncarnati So for that i guess bala would suggest this     `$('#mytable tbody tr :nth-child(3)').hide();` rather than your answer. Check [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/4NgxB/7/).

Comment: Ok I can edit my answer then :) In this case the question was very basic i don't think I need to be downvoted for such a thing.

Comment: @AlexIncarnati sorry for that , i removed for my downvote

Comment: Thanks Bala, Stackoverflow should be a place where developers help each others and where there is a bit of objectivity when judging an answer. Instead sometimes people compete in order to get votes forgetting about the main purpose of having such a great learning tool.